# Content management system to which I could migrate from MediaWiki

Tags: web-development, cms, framework, wiki, mediawiki

MediaWiki maybe too "open" for me.
All of its "management" webpages are open for crawling by crawlers; `noindex` isn't enough because I want to prevent their crawling altogether, not just indexing and my website is in Hebrew, what makes it hard to work with `robots.txt` (which is by itself a dynamic and elusive task given the periodical updates and upgrades).

So,
I seek a content management system which is exactly like MediaWiki, just "closed" --- only its articles and category pages will be open for crawling --- anything else, not.

- FOSS
- Gratis
- An option for easy migrate from a latest MediaWiki version

What will be a CMS like this?

Comment: GitHub repositories can have wiki, but GitHub UI is in English only. GitHub supports Markdown and also, I think, MediaWiki. There are migration scripts around if you Google.